# Can I make Ctrl+Alt+Del go directly into the task manager in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, ctrl-alt-delete

I am using Windows 7 and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> I first go into the welcome screen and only then I can go into the task manager.

I have no use for any other option on this screen, can I change it so the combination will get my directly to the task manager ?

Comment: That screen might be useful, it's "better" at stealing focus from a stuck app than task manager is, or at least this is my perception.

Comment: If I might add, this screen is better since it's a different desktop object (just like the UAC), while taskmgr is just an app.

Comment: @cloneman In fact, it's pretty much the only thing that will interrupt a frozen full-screen application reliably. I've only had one time that it's failed me, and that was when the entire PC froze up.

Comment: This cannot be changed, by design.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for this

Comment: I discovered this some time ago and now that's a great keyboard saver!

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: Windows has [many useful shortcuts](http://www.shortcutmania.com/Windows-7-Keyboard-Shortcuts-printable-cheatsheet.htm), but not so well documented offically. However, this one is mentioned [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Open-Task-Manager).

Comment: Works in vista too. Not tested in XP.

Comment: If you do this often enough, for extra efficiency remap Caps Lock to Esc and enjoy the easy.

Comment: @ruda.almeida works in XP/vista/7/8

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that Ctlr+Shift+Esc is binded by the explorer process, and Ctrl+Alt+Supr is binded by the kernel. So in certain situations, Ctrl+Alt+Supr will always work, but Ctrl+Shift+Esc not.

Comment: @Zequez on my laptop with Win 8 nothing happend after "Ctrl+Alt+Supr" =(

Answer (score 0):

2. Open *Help & Support* from the Start menu.
3. Type `secure logon` in the search box.
4. The result is one option *"Enable Ctrl+Alt+Del"*, choose it.
5. Choose *Advanced* button.
6. Check the box, press *OK* and *Done*.

You may have to restart.

Comment: I do not get that result at step 3.

Answer (score -1):

Another option to getting to task manager quickly is to right click on an open area of the task bar, then choose the "start task manager" option. You can also pin the task manager to the task bar to act as a quick launch if that is what you are looking for.

Of course one there is one last choice, if you go to the start menu in Windows 7 and in the search field at the bottom of the start menu, type "taskmgr" without the quotes, then hit the enter key on your keyboard, that too will launch the task manager directly.

I hope these tips helped out.